# Explain why there is a unique morphism $(\phi\times\phi):G\times G\to H\times H$.

Tags: category-theory

> Let $\phi:G\to H$ be a morphism of category $C$ with products. Explain why there is a unique morphism $$(\phi\times\phi):G\times G\to H\times H$$

How is $G\times G$ defined in a category, where $G$ is an object of the category? 
Motivation: $A\times B$ is the universal object in the category of objects mapping to both $A$ and $B$. Is $G\times G$ the universal object in the category of objects mapping to $G$? If that is the case, wouldn't $\underbrace{G\times G\times\dots\times G}_{\text{n times}}$ be a universal object too?

Also, how is $(\phi\times\phi)$ defined in a category? It seems to me that products are defined only for objects. Is there a category with morphisms as objects that I should consider here?

Comment: Since $A \times B$ is a third object $C$ equipped with morphisms $\pi_0 : C \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_1 : C \rightarrow B$, hence $A \times A$ is an object $C$ equipped with morphisms $\pi_0 : C \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_1 : C \rightarrow A$. It is totally acceptable, when drawing this as a diagram, to draw the object $A$ twice.

Comment: @user18921- What is third object $C$? And is my assertion correct? Would $G^n$ also be a universal object for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: The product $A \times A$ is a triple $(C,\pi_0,\pi_1)$ that is terminal in the category of such triples. And yes, your assertion is correct. **Edit.** I think the key to understanding this is that we're not taking the product of a set $\{A,B\},$ rather we're taking the product of an ordered pair $(A,B)$. So multiplicity matters.

Comment: @user18921- Could you also comment on how $(\phi\times\phi)$ is defined in a category? It seems to me that products are defined only for objects. Is there a category with morphisms as objects that I should consider here?

Comment: Basically, the question is asking you to try to figure out the "natural" way of defining the product of a morphism with itself. (While there *are* categories whose objects are the morphisms of other categories, that's really not really relevant here. Just think of the one category and try to work out the sensible definition of "product of $\varphi : G \rightarrow H$ with itself".)

Comment: "Explain why there is a unique morphism .... " 1. There is no unique(!) morphism. 2. The specification from $G \times G'$ to $G \times G$ doesn't really help to understand this concept ...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is this: To define a morphism $f:A \rightarrow B\times C$ into a product is exactly the same as defining morphisms $f_b:A \rightarrow B$ and $f_c:A \rightarrow C$. So you need to come up with a map $\phi_L:G \times G \rightarrow H$ and $\phi_R:G \times G \rightarrow H$.

One of the other properties of a product $A \times B$ is it comes with projection maps $\pi_L:A \times B \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_R:A \times B\rightarrow B$. That means that $G \times G$ also has these projection maps. Can you see how to put all this information together?

Extra hint: It may or may not be easier for you see what's going on if you take maps $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g:C \rightarrow D$ and define $f \times g:A \times C \rightarrow B \times D$ and specialize this to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can also imagine the so called *arrow category* $C^\to$ of $C$, which has the morphisms of $C$ as objects and commutative squares as morphisms (say from the upper arrow of the square to the lower arrow).

Now, if $\phi:A\to B,\ \psi:C\to D$, then $\phi\times\psi$ will be an arrow $A\times C\to B\times D$. 
In $\mathcal Set$ (and actually in many other categories) it would be the mapping $(a,c)\mapsto (\phi(a),\,\psi(c))$. 
For its categorical construction, see the other answer.

If $(u,v):\alpha\downarrow\phi$ in the arrow category (i.e. $u,v$ are also arrows in $C$ and $v\alpha=\phi u$) $\,$ and $(w,z):\alpha\downarrow\psi$, then use the product property in $C$ for both $A\times C$ and $B\times D$ to define the square $\alpha\to(\phi\times\psi)$ that makes the whole diagram commutative.